# Best way to control python in a loop with keyboard?

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, keyboard, pynput

New to python and wanting to write an app for a Raspberry Pi, but wanting to develop it on my computer first without having to assemble all the buttons, so I was thinking just using a keyboard in replace of buttons would work. But I can't seem to find a good solution for looping a script and watching for keyboard input at the same time.

Specifically, I am trying to run a loop that checks the status of buttons. If any button goes on, it will turn on a shared device. If that button then goes off it will turn off the shared device after a certain time period unless any other button is on. However, if in the time period that the button goes off, but the device has not shut down, another button goes on, the device will not shut down.

I was thinking this would be easier to develop using a keyboard and the numbers 1-8 for the 8 buttons I would have connected to the Pi.

If I use

```
x = input()
```

The script stops and waits for an input, but I need it to continue to run in the background.

So I tried with with the keyboard module

```
import keyboard
import time

while True: #   
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): #
            print("you pressed q")
    except:
        print("no key")
    currenttime = time.time()
    print (f'the new time is {currenttime}' )
    time.sleep(1)
```

But it only accepts the keyboard input sometimes. Like not while it is sleeping, which I'm using as an example of if the script was busy doing other things.

I found this code searching around

```
from pynput import keyboard
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Aside from the security issues, it grabs the keyboard input but I don't know where to put my loop.

I also played around a bit with tkinter, but since I'm not trying to build a GUI, this didn't seem like the right path.

Comment: Yes, tkinter is not the best approach. Have you tried using `threading`?

Comment: Threading sounded complicated, but I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: please clarify the exacts issue, what are you even trying to achieve, just have code that can also in parallel register keystrokes? also there is a `keyboard` module. why did you want to use `tkinter` anyways? it is a GUI library

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into event binding: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-binding-function-in-tkinter/